# Android annotationProcessor

Tags: android, build.gradle

In my project app dependencies I have one library which requires annotationProcessor, but when I try to build the project I get this error:

> Error:(44, 0) Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [...] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

The **build.gradle** is like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 24
   buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

   defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 10
      targetSdkVersion 24
      ...

      jackOptions {
          enabled true
      }
   }

   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
   ...

}

dependencies {
   Another dependencies ... 

   compile '...'
   annotationProcessor '...'
}
```

Note that I am using jackOptions enabled and Java 8 version to this project.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I had that update my Android Studio to a version 2.2 or newer, because the annotationProcessor was implemented only from this version.

Thus, the first thing to do is to check if there is a new Android Studio update available on the Beta or Canary channel (at this moment, the 2.2 version is not available on stable channel). With a new Android Studio IDE version we are enable to use the annotationProcessor.

The top-level build file (the build for the project and no to the your app module) will contain the following classpath dependency (in my case the 2.2.0-rc2 version):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc2'
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The version 2.2 is available on stable channel, so, you don't need worry about the (more) possibilities of getting troubles on Android Studio's versions which are available on other channels.